# Select between a specific day of current month and previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server, between

I've been searching this, but only got answers for specified dates.

The problem I am facing is:

Return all the data between the 20th of the previous month and the 20th of the current month.

```
select name, data, activity from Table
where (year(data) = year(getdate()) and month(data) = month(getdate())-1 and day(data) >= 20) and (year(data) = year(getdate()) and month(data) = month(getdate()) and day(data) <= 20)

select name, data, activity from Table
where year(data) = year(getdate()) and month(data) >= month(getdate())-1 and day(data) >= 20
```

This last one would work, but it won't return any result for the current month.

I've tried several where clauses but it seams that that only specifying the dates would work. Is there a way to dynamically do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `eomonth()` to compare the months:

```
select t.*
from t
where ( day(data) >= 20 and eomonth(data) = eomonth(dateadd(month, -1, getdate())) ) or
      ( day(data) < 20 and eomonth(data) = emonth(getdate()) );
```

You can do this in SQL Server 2008, but the date arithmetic is a bit nastier.  One method is to subtract 21 days and check if it is the previous month:

```
select t.*
from t
where (year(dateadd(day, -21, data)) * 12 + month(dateadd(day, -21, data)) =
       year(getdate()) * 12 + month(getdate()) - 1
      )
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, but it seams the company is using SQL Server 2008 and the eomonth only comes on 2012. Is there any way to simulate the eomonth in 2008? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As ofmonth does not exist on 2008, I've translated the @Gordon correct answer with:

```
( day(data) >= 20 and CONVERT(DATE, dateadd(mm, datediff(mm,0, data)+1,-1)) = CONVERT(DATE, dateadd(mm, datediff(mm,0, dateadd(month, -1, getdate()))+1,-1)) ) or
  ( day(data) < 20 and CONVERT(DATE, dateadd(mm, datediff(mm,0, data)+1,-1)) = CONVERT(DATE, dateadd(mm, datediff(mm,0, current_timestamp)+1,-1)) )
```

and it worked.

Thanks